# Random or fixed effects? GLM or GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics, nested-data

I am interested in the behavioral response of floral visitors to a treatment, applied in a paired fashion within plants. That is, one stem on each plant receives the treatment, and another stem serves as a control. The response that I am interested in is total number of flowers visited per day. Each plant is only used for one day and we sampled for a total of three days.

The number of flowers on each stem varies within and between plants, and will affect visitation. However, I am not interested in this effect.

I do not know whether it is more appropriate to specify a glmm, with flower number nested within individual plant as a random effect, and date as a separate random effect, such as this:

```r
    mod1 <- glmer(data=data, total_flr_vis ~ treatment + 
            (1|date) + (1|individual/flr_num), family=poisson)
```

or whether it is more appropriate to specify a `glm` such as this:

```r
    mod2 <- glm(data=data, total_flr_vis ~ treatment + 
              individual + date + flr_num, family=quasipoisson)
```

(I've used `quasipoisson` here as the data are over-dispersed when the effects are all fixed)

I think that it is more philosophically sound to use the `glmm`, and would go with that if the results of each model were qualitatively similar. However, they are very different (output below). Specifically, the `glmm` tells me that there is a significant effect of treatment, whereas the `glm` does not.

Thus, I would like to be extra careful that I am using the most appropriate model.

```r
mod1 <- glmer(data=newdata, total_flr_vis ~ treatment + 
         (1|date) +    (1|individual/flr_num), family=poisson)
mod1
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  
      (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
     Family: poisson  ( log )
    Formula: total_flr_vis ~ treatment + (1 | date) + (1 | individual/flr_num)
       Data: newdata
          AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
     457.3714  472.4908 -223.6857  447.3714       147 
    Random effects:
     Groups             Name        Std.Dev.
     flr_num:individual (Intercept) 2.864   
     individual         (Intercept) 1.008   
     date               (Intercept) 0.000   
    Number of obs: 152, groups:  flr_num:individual, 149; individual, 42; date, 3
     Fixed Effects:
    (Intercept)   treatmentR  
     -1.712       -1.503  

summary(mod1)
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
     (Laplace  Approximation) ['glmerMod']
     Family: poisson  ( log )
    Formula: total_flr_vis ~ treatment + (1 | date) + (1 | individual/flr_num)
       Data: newdata

         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
       457.4    472.5   -223.7    447.4      147 

    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -1.0196 -0.2783 -0.1751  0.1270  0.6132 

    Random effects:
     Groups             Name        Variance Std.Dev.
     flr_num:individual (Intercept) 8.201    2.864   
     individual         (Intercept) 1.015    1.008   
     date               (Intercept) 0.000    0.000   
    Number of obs: 152, groups:  flr_num:individual, 149; individual, 42; date, 3

    Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)  -1.7117     0.6530  -2.621 0.008757 ** 
    treatmentR   -1.5032     0.3959  -3.797 0.000146 ***
     ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
               (Intr)
    treatmentR -0.165
```

---

Compared to:

```r
mod2 = glm(data=newdata, total_flr_vis ~ treatment + individual + 
      date + flr_num, family=quasipoisson)
mod2

    Call:  glm(formula = total_flr_vis ~ treatment + individual + 
   date + 
        flr_num, family = quasipoisson, data = newdata)

    Coefficients:
    (Intercept)   treatmentR   individual         date      flr_num  
      -0.8641906   -0.4262042   -0.0004565    0.0072634    0.0150606  

    Degrees of Freedom: 151 Total (i.e. Null);  147 Residual
    Null Deviance:      1011 
    Residual Deviance: 963.4    AIC: NA  

summary(mod2)

    Call:
    glm(formula = total_flr_vis ~ treatment + individual + date + 
        flr_num, family = quasipoisson, data = newdata)

    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -3.4249  -1.9918  -1.6997  -0.5174  10.9899  

    Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept) -0.8641906 20.9133728  -0.041    0.967
    treatmentR  -0.4262042  0.3971152  -1.073    0.285
    individual  -0.0004565  0.0179801  -0.025    0.980
    date         0.0072634  0.1155358   0.063    0.950
    flr_num      0.0150606  0.0100614   1.497    0.137

    (Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 11.20508)

        Null deviance: 1011.19  on 151  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance:  963.39  on 147  degrees of freedom
    AIC: NA

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post a sample of your data, e.g. first 10-20 rows of your dataframe? There are multiple things about your models that don't make a lot of sense to me. (1) Does `date` only have three levels, are the dates the same for all flowers? Then including date as a random effect is arguably suboptimal, it's too few levels for a random effect. (2) What is `individual`? Is it an id number of a flower? Including it as a continuous variable in your glm model does not make *any* sense at all. You should include it as a factor. (3) Similarly, `flr_num` as random is strange. Etc.

Comment: @amoeba (1) There are 14 levels of `date`; (2) Yes, `individual` is an ID (plant, not flower). I'm sorry that it isn't clear from my code, but it is defined as a factor; (3) I included `flr_num` as random as it represents the display size (number of open flowers at the time of sampling) of each individual on each day of sampling. It changes at each sampling date; the levels would not be repeated exactly were I to run the experiment again; the value is expected to have an influence on visitor behavior, but is not something that I am interested in testing.